# Avoid deep link calls onGenerateRoute in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I'm trying to handle deeplinking in my Flutter app with uni_links package.

Is there a way to avoid onGenerateRoute is called by the launch deep linking? I have my own routing logic and I just need to get the deeplink string (I already do) and nothing else, I don't need to be routed anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For android,

in AndroidManifest.xml inside `<activity>` tag, please add

`<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="false" />`

More info: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking#enable-deep-linking-on-android

For iOS
Inside Info.plist, add

`<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key> <NO/>`

More info: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking#enable-deep-linking-on-ios

Comment: I only tried Android and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are the values for Android `false` and iOS `true`?

Comment: you are right. for iOS it should be NO.  Ref. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links#2-adjust-ios-build-settings Step 6